# How to click a blurred sun?

Tags: html, css, text, click, blur

I want to hint the user to tap on the sun, so I thought of putting some text on top of it. However the sun is blurred, causing the text to be blurred too!

I tried to override the blur effect, wrapping the text in a `span`, but it seems like the effect from the class of the `div` dominates. Any thoughts/ideas?

HTML:

```
<div class="sun">Click</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sun {
  width: 20em; height: 20em;
  background: #ffff99;
  border-radius: 10em;
  animation: flow 10s infinite alternate;
  transform:translate(-30%, -30%) scale(0.2);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

You can view it live in this <kbd>[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/r3un0bpd/)</kbd>.

Comment: box-shadow could be an alternative for the sun : https://jsfiddle.net/r3un0bpd/1/ with effect blur/unblur onclick https://jsfiddle.net/r3un0bpd/3/ to notice if difference from blur is fine

Comment: Nice alternative @GCyrillus, if you could post an answer, tidying up that text, I would upvote it! ;)

Comment: okay, did &  i added a CSS toggle  faking the blur effect. thx for the feedback anyway ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a parent div and set `position:absolute` to the span:

```css
.sun {
  width: 20em; height: 20em;
  background: #ffff99;
  border-radius: 10em;
  animation: flow 10s infinite alternate;
  transform:translate(-30%, -30%) scale(0.2);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
.relative {
  position:relative;
}
.absl {
  position:absolute;
  left:46px;
  top:52px;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="sun"></div>
  <span class="absl">Click</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The blur effect on the parent element will be applied to the child element, so you can't use it this way.

What you can do is wrap the two elements with a container and position them relatively to the container element:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.sun {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20em; height: 20em;
  background: #ffff99;
  border-radius: 10em;
  animation: flow 10s infinite alternate;
  transform:translate(-30%, -30%) scale(0.2);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
.container span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sun"></div>
  <span style="-webkit-filter: blur(0px)">Click</span>
</div>
```

Comment: you are too fast brother

Comment: @Dekel for balance, and because the other answer has the text tidied up.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `box-shadow` and rescale the span so it can be read ;).

*Added a toggle effect on click to see the alike blur effect from shadow via [tabindex](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute)*

> The `tabindex` content attribute allows authors to control whether an element is supposed to be focusable, whether it is supposed to be reachable using sequential focus navigation, and what is to be the relative order of the element for the purposes of sequential focus navigation. The name "tab index" comes from the common use of the "tab" key to navigate through the focusable elements. The term "tabbing" refers to moving forward through the focusable elements that can be reached using sequential focus navigation.

```css
.sun:first-child {
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  background: #ffff99;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), 0 0 5em 1em #ffff99;
  border-radius: 10em;
  animation: flow 10s infinite alternate;
  transform: translate(-30%, -30%) scale(0.2);
  transition: 0.25s;
}

[tabindex] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sun+.sun {
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  background: #ffff99;
  border-radius: 10em;
  animation: flow 10s infinite alternate;
  transform: translate(-30%, -90%) scale(0.2);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(5);
  transform-origin:top left;
}

.sun:first-child:focus {
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), 0 0 0 0 #ffff99;
}
body {
background:skyblue; /* ;) */
```

```html
<div class="sun" tabindex="0"><span style="-webkit-filter: blur(0px)">Click to toggle blur</span></div>
<div class="sun"><span style="-webkit-filter: blur(0px)">original</span></div>
```

Comment: Amazing! Which part of your code emulates the click?

Comment: @gsamaras tabindex attribute allows the element to catch the click event

Comment: Cool! And then this `.sun:first-child:focus` comes into play? Sorry for bugging you, but this could be the solution I can use..If I get how it works. =)

Comment: @gsamaras yes, that's the idea `:focus` or `:active` to trigger style. If you do not want to use a div, you may use a link where `tabindex` is not necessary. But CSS will not fire any script beside CSS `transition` or `animation`  more about tabindex https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute